# set initial react component state in constructor or componentWillMount?

Tags: reactjs

In react components is it preferred to set the initial state in the constructor() or componentWillMount()?

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.setState({key: value});
  }
}
```

or

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  componentWillMount(props){
    this.setState({key: value});
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137740/which-kinds-of-initialization-is-more-appropriate-in-constructor-vs-componentwil

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In the constructor is preferable when using ES6 classes, but don't use the `setState` API, rather do like so:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { key: value };
  }
}
```

Also, if you have class properties available to you (babel stage 1) then you can do the following:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  state = { key: value };

  render() {
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Because I remember reading to never mutate this.state directly : 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, don't use it when setting initial state. :) Everywhere else yes.

Comment: Why is it ok in this case?

Comment: Also why is it better to use the constructor than componentWillMount?

Comment: It's a direct recommendation from the React team to set the state in the constructor when using ES6 classes. [Read about that here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes).  I assume there is some level of internals that we are unaware of which require the initial state to be set before any lifecycle events get fired.

Comment: I'm reading a book and it sets initial state in componentWillMount which made me curious why not in constructor. Just saying that not all books can be trusted for best practice.

Comment: Why use `this.state` in your first code and only `state` in the second?I dint get that

Comment: +Abhinav first code refers to the class's property from a function in the same class, while the second code declares the class property, along with its initial value (so `this` is not needed). Essentially, the assignment does not happen in a function context (although the transpiled version does but that's an implementation detail).