# Make button disable using react failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
render(){
  const { loading } = this.state;
  return(
    <div>
      {!loading ? <input disabled type='text' /> : <input type='text' />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Above jsx make sense? I didn't get any compliation error, just that I got a warning from react saying `Unknown prop`disabbed`on <input> tag.`

How to changed the attr of the button to disabled the correct way? Imagine if my input has lots of class of css, do I need to repeat them too? I felt it's redundant.

Comment: <input disabled={loading} type='text' />

Comment: Note that you are rendering a text field actually. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a conditional rendering on the `input` tag. You can do it the following way

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true
    }
  }
  render(){
    const { loading } = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <input disabled={loading} type='text'/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Note that using `constructor` to set the initial `state` is discouraged, also, when you use `super`, you should pass the `...props` to it as well in case you are going to use `this.props` in the same context. Better to use the class properties syntax. (`state = { ...stuff }`)

Comment: @FezVrasta I agree with you that props should be passed to the constructor and super otherwise it can lead to potential bugs. However why is it discouraged to set state constructor. see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructorhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782403/set-initial-react-component-state-in-constructor-or-componentwillmount   and

Comment: The doc makes use of the `constructor` because it's more widespread, but it leads to more bugs because of what I explained. You can refer to `this.props` inside a class property and avoid any `super` quirkiness. https://gist.github.com/FezVrasta/630e92170d20618fc35d55c83fefcd2d