# How to set initial state with using ES6 class in React?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have created the below class

```
class App extends Component{
     render() {
         return (
             <div className="app"></div>
         );
     }
}
```

How do i set initial state? 
 `getInitialState()` isn't working?
what am i doing wrong? 
 The react docs are also not helping.

Comment: check react doc [How to set initial state in es-6 class component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37782403/1531971 This looks like a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set initial react component state in constructor or componentWillMount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782403/set-initial-react-component-state-in-constructor-or-componentwillmount)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: 'Hello World'
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.text}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You may also want to check out this post about the difference between when to use a constructor and when to use getInitialState.

[What is the difference between using constructor vs getInitialState in React / React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668326/what-is-the-difference-between-using-constructor-vs-getinitialstate-in-react-r)

Answer (score 26):

There is also a shortcut of Jenna's great answer, which doesn't use `constructor` or `this`:

```jsx
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        text: 'Hello World'
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.text}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

A simplified example shows that the output is the same in both cases:

- [Babel with constructor](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECCAO9oG8BQ0PWAewHYQBcAnAV2AOyIAoBKFdTRggCwEsIA6QsAgU2gC89RiMx8AHgQBc0AOQAJXiBDZoAdUogAJrIaiAvgG490fSaK9cW3tTppRGCwRJFc0KiYfQAPFtYA3AD5PL0xkFnYuAh5eDgkCM1DMbwB6PyCQjBpjRjN9IA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)
- [Babel without constructor](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECCAO9oG8BQ0PQgFzNgptALwrqbkEAe2AXNAOQAS-IIA9tAOpsBOIAJvTIYAvgG5h0HvgB2_fDwAUASlLly07AFceM6IsnrMAHn4BLAG4A-Q0fXJsACzMQAdDjz5XVbCNtHjAHpza39oZQlyPxEgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

But if we extend a parent class, the transpiled output does differ, since the number of arguments in the constructor is unknown.

Comment: According to [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/9a82ca465ae47f4273c65ad3fb87fd27/59607892ef56715fd0c75f3d45f094a676a9a3ff), this is called a ClassProperty.

Comment: After discovering this syntax, we considered using it for methods too, as an alternative to binding. However [this article](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1) convinced us otherwise!